# Sending data from swing to Servlet

Tags: java, swing, servlets

How to send data (form data) from a Swing to the servlet. Is it as simple as specifying in action attribute as in html(form)?

I am passing data to Servlet using this code:

```
URL url = new URL(targetURL); 
connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

What is that I have to pass to url i.e in place of `targetURL` (do I need to mention Servlet location) so that I can retrieve values in the servlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`HttpUrlConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) in order to communicate using `HttpRequest`

**See**

- [how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: url = new URL(targetURL);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
           "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");I have seen this code in some link,targeturl=target o the servlet-is it correct?? Do we need to set all the connection parameters like setreqmethod,set req property???

Answer (score 1):

It works just the same as Java Applets, you can find more information here: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/AppletsFaq#servlet

I'd highly reccommend BalusC's introduction to Servlet's and DAO's [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) as well.