# Receiving data in servlet from swing

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, servlets

I connected to servlet from swing using `HttpURLConnection`. I did not understand this code:

```
 DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
 connection.getOutputStream()); //connection is obj of HttpurlConnection class.

 wr.writeBytes(un);//un contains username retrieved from textbox from the swing 
 wr.flush();
 wr.close();
```

What is the way to read values in the servlet, so that I can do further process (like inserting into database etc..)

Is there any method other than above method or can I get values through request object?

Comment: Didn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090580/sending-data-from-swing-to-servlet) help you

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to decorate the request input stream with a `DataInputStream`:

```
DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
String un = dataIn.readUTF();
```

Comment: You would write this in your servlet.